# App not displaying view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an application that uses a countdown timer to display a view in the onFinish() using the setContentView(R.layout.id).  Everything works fine as long as the user does not hit home, timer ends and the layout it displayed plus a tone is played.

However, if the user hits home or back when the timer ends and onFinish() is called all I get is the tone, the layout is not displayed.

How do I get the layout to be displayed?  Is it even possible?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving whatever is called via setContentView into a separate activity so at the end of the timer you call startActivity(...) which would bring that activity, with the view you want, to the foreground?

Answer (score 0):

Is it happening in the UI Thread, sounds like something that might not work in another thread.